# Error when trying to get token using Managed Service Identity in a multi-container azure web app service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-managed-identity, azure-pipelines-release-task

We have the following scenario:

**Current working setup**

1. Web API project using a single DockerFile
2. A release pipe line with an 'Azure App Service deploy' task.

**Proposed new setup**

1. Web API project using multi container Docker Compose file
2. A release pipe line with an 'Azure Web App for Containers' task.

Upon deploying the new setup we receive the below error message:

```
ERROR - multi-container unit was not started successfully

Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
(Parameters: Connection String: XXX, Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: 
https://login.windows.net/xxxxx. Exception Message: 
Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. 
Access token could not be acquired. Connection refused)
```

The exception thrown is because it can't connect to Azure MSI (Managed Service Identity). It does this to obtain a token before connecting to key vault.

I have tried the following based upon some research and solutions others have found:

1. Connecting with `"RunAs=App"` (this seems to be the default parameter-less constructor anyway)
2. Building up the connection string myself manually by pulling the `"MSI_SECRET"` environment variable from the machine. This is always blank.
3. Restarting MSI.
4. Upgrading and downgrading `AppAuthentication` package

MSI appears to be configured correctly as it works perfectly with our current working setup so we can rule that out.
It's worth noting that this is System assigned identity not a user assigned one.

The documentation that states which services support managed identites only mentions 'Azure Container Instances' not 'Azure Managed Container Instances' and that is for Linux/Preview too so that it could be not supported.

[Services that support managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities#azure-container-instances)

We've spent a considerable amount of time getting to this point with the configuration and deployment and it would be great if we could resolve this last issue.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there currently is no multi-container support for managed identities. The multi-container feature is in preview and so does not have all its functionality working yet.

However, the documentation you linked to is also not as clear about the supported scenarios, so I am working on getting this documentation updated to better clarify this. I can update this answer once that's done.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply @nonik that saves us going down the path of trying to get it working with the task alone. I'm thinking that if we populate the data needed for the token call within our API (passed down from release task environment variables) it should hopefully work. Would you happen to know if this would work before we go down that path?

Comment: Hi @Nishant-MSFTIdentity, yes some further information to it would be good please. We've done a work around which involved deploying separate container instances in order to release for now.

Comment: @hutchonoid Thank You for the response. Let me check if I can find further information on this. I would update here as soon as I have something.